# Woocommerce checkout show order note field only when shipping method Local Pickup selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How to show order note field only when shipping method Local Pickup selected otherwise hide order note field.

Answer (score -1):

please try this.

```
function checkout_update_script() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {

            $checkout_form = $( 'form.checkout' );

            $checkout_form.on( 'change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function() {
                var payment_method = $checkout_form.find('[name="payment_method"]').serializeArray()[0]['value'];
                $checkout_form.find( '[name="order_comments"], [for="order_comments"]' ).toggle( payment_method == 'paypal' )
            }).find('input[name="payment_method"]').trigger('change');


        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_update_script', 999 );
```

this will show order notes only when paypal is selected. Please change according to your needs. At the very least you need to change `payment_method == 'paypal'`.